# Cannot log in to my android phone anymore

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-3, keyboard, encryption

Few days ago I got firmware update in my S3. After update, I realized the default QWERTY keyboard is lost. There was only voice input. Then, I downloaded painfully "Go Keyboard" with voice search in android market then everything was fine.

Today, I had to encrypt my phone because I wanted to use my company's Google app service in my phone as well. I encrypted phone with password given. When phone re-started and asked me password, there is no keyboard to type in. Go Keyboard probably doesn't appear before decrypting phone because it is an installed app.

Now I have many, files, pictures which are not in cloud. What should I do in this case. Can't I enter password from my PC someway.

Please help me if you can.

Comment: Can you just plug an external keyboard using USB [tag:otg]?